# How to select option in select list?

Tags: angularjs, dropdownbox

I have option element in select:

```
$scope.countries = {0 : 'Select country...'};
```

And `ng-model="selected"` is integer 0;

But option is not selected. How I can select option with 0?

Comment: could you be more specific? suppose you have countries={ 'zero': 0, 'one': 1}, do you want to select countries.zero (= 0)?

Comment: are you asking how to do a default value?

Comment: I want select item with `0`

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I understood what you were trying to do...
but I think you want to show the text when the value 0 is selected in the ngModel... so you want the ngOptions to go by the value but show the text?

so you want something like:

ng-options="**country as country.id** for country in countries track by country.id"
please check.... so you can actually do something like

```
<select ng-options="item.subItem as item.label for item in values track by item.id" ng-model="selected">


    $scope.values = [{
  id: 1,
  label: 'aLabel',
  subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
}, {
  id: 2,
  label: 'bLabel',
  subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
}];

$scope.selected = { name: 'aSubItem' };
```

please check
[ngOptions docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: Look please again my question, I have object `$scope.countries = {0 : 'Select country...'};` and I need to select option where value is `0`

Comment: please provide a quick jsfiddle or plunker I will understand from there and solve what you need... I still dont understand if your talking about preselecting a default value or you want to have selected as 0 but have in the select the value 'Select country', again if you do what I told you then all you need is to preselect the selected to 0 and it will show the title instead of the value... this might require you to change the object to {id:0,title:'Select Country'}

Answer (score 0):

If I got you correctly then you are looking for something like this

```
<html>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HomeCtrl">

    <select ng-model="selected" ng-options="v for (k,v) in country ">
    </select>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>

    var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('HomeCtrl', ['$scope',  function($scope) {

        $scope.selected='Select country...';  // dafault to be displayed

        $scope.country={0 : 'Select country...', 1:'France', 2:'India', 3:'USA'};

    }]);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Note** :- The key of an object will always have to be of string data type. You cannot use integer or number , that will be treated as string only.